# Octobercms YAML select

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, yaml, octobercms

How would i be able to select another table in Octobercms's YAML configuration right now I have it like this.:

```
season:
    label: Season
    type: relation
    select: concat(title, ' - ', ' Season ', number)
```

the selects the title and the number, but what I would like to do is to select multiple tables and use concat to for a specific selection of columns.

From the answer below I have tried this but i wouldnt know where to go from there. Basically from the episodes feild.yaml it contains:

```
    season:
        label: Season
        descriptionFrom: description
        span: auto
        type: partial
        path: ~/plugins/test/movie/models/season/_content_column.htm
```

I want to be able to grab the season of which the episode is related towards the movie. The previous code which was a relation showed "all" of the seasons. I want to show the speicif seasons for that movie that was created in the movie to be in the dropdown for the episode to select.

Answer (score 1):

You can do multiple selection from different tables manual through [partial column](http://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#column-partial).

Comment: how would i apply this?